# Shuffling batches of tensors with variable length features

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm having trouble sampling my data in TensorFlow. I have a bunch of samples, each made up of 15 signals of different lengths. I want to randomly pull samples from this group. What is the correct way of doing this?

I'm getting this error when I try to shuffle the batch of tensors:

> ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 30 and 5
>       From merging shape 9 with other shapes. for 'shuffle_batch/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [1185], [1185], [7500], [7500], [15000], [15000], [150], [150], [30], [30], [5], [5], [5], [5], [5].

The error is happening in here:

```
example, label = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [example, label],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    capacity=capacity,
    min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue,
    num_threads=num_preprocess_threads)
```

Thanks

Comment: What are the shapes of `example` and `label` before you pass them to `tf.train.shuffle_batch`?

Comment: The input shapes are:
[1185], [1185], [7500], [7500], [15000], [15000], [150], [150], [30], [30], [5], [5], [5], [5], [5]
The label shape is:
[5,]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.train.shuffle_batch()` takes an optional `enqueue_many` argument that I think does what you want. It lets you pass multiple tensors of different shapes, where each Tensor represents one part of a batch of inputs.

"If enqueue_many is True, tensors is assumed to represent a batch of examples, where the first dimension is indexed by example, and all members of tensors should have the same size in the first dimension. If an input tensor has shape [*, x, y, z], the output will have shape [batch_size, x, y, z]."

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/shuffle_batch

Hope that helps!